# How would one  detect if external command exists in a script?

Tags: shell-script, utilities, executable

Is there a way to detect if an external command exists (i.e. wget, svn)?

More specifically today, i was trying to run one of my scripts i wrote and the person didn't have `wget` or svn installed.

The script just downloads a file extracts it or uses svn to export the trunk.

Comment: `wget` and `svn` are not functions, they're external commands (also called utilities, which includes built-in utilities). Functions are defined by shell code and live inside the current shell instance. External commands are stored in executable files and can be implemented in any language.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure about the terminology there; still have a lot to learn.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu or Debian you may be interested in the `command-not-found` package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Bash the `type` shell built-in gives information about the executable things: aliases, functions, executables. See `help type` for details.

```sh
# just check for existence
type -t 'yourfunction' > /dev/null || echo 'error: yourfunction not found'

# explicitly check for given type
[[ "$( type -t 'yourfunction' )" != 'function' ]] && \
    echo 'error: yourfunction not found or is not a function'
```